# solar Panel Calculations help required?

Tags: solar-cell

My father runs a solar company. He asked me the following question:

> A customer comes to me to ask for setting up a system that will help him use 10 bulbs each of power 10 W for 10 hours.

Assuming my area has a sunlight duration of 10 hours, how can I calculate these values (number of panels, size of battery, etc)?

I can provide more information if more variables are required.

EDIT: I don't have any knowledge in this sector so all I want is what formulas to use what to take under consideration.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: We really need you to show us what you have done, and where you are stuck. If there is something fundamental that you don't understand,  or something that you aren't sure of, please ask that *specific* question and we can help you better. As worded, you have asked us to do all of the work.

Comment: We don't just give answers to homework problems here.  And -1 for attempting to diguise the homework.

Comment: I think what's puzzling everyone is why the owners and staff of a "solar company" are unable to figure this simple problem out, and are asking the owner's family to help. If you could explain the context, you might get more help. Otherwise, it looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: My father runs the company actually a small market sort of thing and usually finds the answer using trial and error. i decided help him by making a software to ease this task but have no idea on how to proceed with the calculations, my father is not a very good in explaining  so i was hoping for help over here. this is not an assignment but an example of the details gets from the customer. i was hoping for the formulas or tactics for the solar setup from the panel to the battery to every thing else in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Location is Kuwait - lots of sunshine :-).

Where are you?  It is essential to know this.
Nowhere on earth gets 10 hours full sun/day except near the poles.
See www.gaisma.com for details. eg

Kuwait sunshine hours - [**Jalīb aš-Šuyūẖ**](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/jalib-as-suyuh.html)
7.75 average sunshine hours / day in June
3.14 average sunshine hours / day in December

Better than:

[Delhi sunshine here](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/delhi.html)
4th chart top line =
7 hours average in May.
3.31 hours average in December.

[Bangalore here](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/bangalore.html)
6.45 hours average in April.
4.36 hours of full sun equivalent per day in November.

---

**Energy needed:**

1 x  10 Watt bulb uses 10 Watt hours of energy in 1 hour.
8 x 10 Watt bulbs uses 8  x 10 Watts = 80 Watt hours of energy in 1 hour.
1 x  10 Watt bulb uses 5 x 10 Watt hours of energy in 5 hours.

From the above you can work out how many WATT-HOURS A x B Watt bulbs will use in C hours

> Watt hours of energy needed = Bulb_Wattage x number_of_bulbs  x  hours_per_night

As an example lets say we worked out you needed 350 Watt-Hours of energy per night.

In Delhi in December you get an AVERAGE of ~=  3.3 hours of full sun equivalent per day (less on the road from Delhi to Agra :-) )
To get 350 Watt hours of energy in 3.3 hours - PV_Watts = Energy/hours of sun = 350/3.3 = 106 Watts.
As an initial "rule of thumb"you will need about DOUBLE the panel watts as the basic calculation suggests in real life. So you need about 2 x 106 W ~~= a 200 Watt of 250 Watt panel.
Note that this is for the example only 350 Watt-hour requirement above. The answer will change with your data.

Sanity check:

200W PV x 3.3 h = 660 Wh.
Desired = 350 ~+ 2:1 = OK.

---

Kuwait sunshine hours - [**Jalīb aš-Šuyūẖ**](http://www.gaisma.com/en/location/jalib-as-suyuh.html)

The chart below, from the above page, shows average hours of equivalent full sunshine per day for each month of the year in Jalīb aš-Šuyūẖ - the result is liable to be very similar anywhere in Kuwait.

Lowest is an average of 3.14 sunshine hours per day in December. 
That means that for each 100 Watt panel IF you operate it optimally you can get about 3.14 hours x 100 Watts = 314 Watt hours of energy out.

> Energy for lights per night = 
>   Load Wh (Watt hours) = Watts-per-light x hours-of-operation x number-of-lights

A modern LED bulb can work VERY well with 5 Watts. 10 Watts better again.
Most lights would not be used for 10 hours / night. Some will. 
If you have say 10 Watts x 6 hours x 4 lights then
Watt hours 10 x 6 x 4 = 240 Watt hours.

> Battery capacity in A.h (Amp.hours) = Watt.hours/Volts
>   For a 12V battery 
>   Ah = Wh/12

For lead acid batteries you do not want to discharge below 50% capacity - and even less is better. Call battery available capacity Z_battery. For 50% available capacity Zbattery = 0.5

Some energy is lost in wiring and in a converter from battery voltage to light voltage etc.  At most maybe 80% of battery energy is typically used and it may be less.
Call battery to light conversion efficiency = Z_LED
For 80% battery to LED conversion efficiency Z_LED = 0.80

If you need 240 Watt hours of energy (as above) then battery capacity needed = 
Wh_load / Z_LED / Z_Battery
or

> Battery Wh =  Wh_load / (Z_LED x Z_Battery)

= 240 /(0.8 x 0.5) = 240 / 0.4 = 600 Wh battery capacity.
For a 12V battery Ah_battery = Wh/12 = 600/12 = 50 Ah.
Making the battery larger to much larger will make it last longer to  much longer - or allow operation after one of Kuwait's 26 or so wet days per year :-).

For the above system a 50 Ah battery is the minimal need and a 10 Ah is better.

In your original 10W x 10 hours x 10 bulb request Watt hours = 10 x 10 x 10 = 1000 Watt hours - so battery needs to be 1000Wh/240 Wh times larger
or about 4 x larger.
So at least 200 Ah at 12V and maybe 400 Ah.

The PV (solar) panel Watt hour capacity per day needs to be maybe 50% to 100% larger than the load energy need. If you have an MPPT controller it will maximise panel energy use.

Say PV panel needs to be 50% larger than load  energy used per day.
Call the factor Z_PV so for a load energy use of 100 Wh and PV panel capacity of 150 Wh then Z_PV = 100/150 = 0.666

> **PV_Wh = Load_Wh / (Z_LED x Z_PV)**

and

> **PV Watts = Load_Wh / (Z_LED x Z_PV x Sunshine_hours_per_day)**

So for the 240 Wh load energy use
PV Watt hours = 240 Wh load / (0.8 x 0.666)
PV Watt hours = 450 Wh.
PV Watts = PV Wh / Sunshine hours per day.
For ~= 3 hours sun per day worst case then 
PV Watts = 450 / 3 = 150 Watts.

For the 10W x 10 bulbs x 10 hours load
Load Wh = 1000 Wh  as
PV Watts = Load_Wh / (Z_LED x Z_PV x Sunshine_hours_per_day)
PV Watts = 1000 / (0.8 x 0.666x 3) = 625 Watts of PV panel.

In summer much smaller PV panels would work but the required battery capacity is unchanged.

[image]

---

Comment: Kuwait and what variables are missing? Not an assignment just looking for method to solve this.

Comment: For the battery?

Comment: @RazaHassan - Answer substantially updated. Please read and confirm that you understand this.

Comment: yes i have understood this much but what about the controller and inverter?

Comment: @RazaHassan there is no controller or inverter in your question. You need to spell out your needs in a bit more detail. Do you have to use mains lighting - LED low voltage is perhaps more efficient. What inverters and controllwers do you use now? etc